# Generating nested data structures in a HList-like style

Tags: scala, types, nested, shapeless

Given:

```
val a = "foo" :: "bar" :: MyNil[Float]()
```

I'd like that `a.ArrayType` resolves to `Array[Array[Float]]`, as well as `a.toList` generates `Seq("foo", "bar")`. For a longer list, the `a.ArrayType` should be nested deeper, but the leaf type should stay the same.

I am trying to define a data structure that allows the above, but failed with my own tries so far.

I have some approaches that all do not work completely. Either I fail to get the induction step, or the induction start. Maybe there is some shapeless-enabled solution that I fail to see? This is what I have so far where I fail to get the induction start:

```
trait NestedArrays[A] {
  type BaseType = A
  type ArrayType <: Array[_]
  val name: String
  val t: NestedArrays[A]

  def ::(name: String): ::[A] = new ::(name, this)

  def toList: List[String] = name :: t.toList
}

case class ::[A](name: String, t: NestedArrays[A]) extends NestedArrays[A] {
  override type BaseType = t.BaseType
  override type ArrayType = Array[t.ArrayType]
}

class HANil[A] extends NestedArrays[A] {
  override type BaseType = A
  override type ArrayType = A

  override val t: NestedArrays[A] = null
  override val name: String = null

  override def toList: List[String] = Nil
}

object HANil {
  def apply[A](): NestedArrays[A] = new HANil[A]

  // val test = "bar" :: "baz" :: "foo" :: begin[Float]("bal")
  val test = "foo" :: "bar" :: HANil[Float]()
  //val test = begin[Float]("boo")
  val a = Array.ofDim[Float](2, 2).asInstanceOf[test.ArrayType]
}
```

My other solutions vary around whether `ArrayType` must be an array or not (if not, the induction step fails, but the start works), or whether `NestedArrays` has a type parameter or not, but it's all detail work. I'd be happy about any other solution with other approaches as well, although I guess I'd need some path-dependent typing in all solutions. Maybe some implicit parameters can guide my way?

Comment: Do I observe correctly that the list contains elements of only type `String`, and you simply attach a "type tag" (`float`) which you want to use to parameterize your nested `Array`? So you do not really have an `HList`, but you use the "`HList`" merely to count the nesting level?

Comment: Correct. The more elements in the list, the more nesting I want to have. It is not a shapeless `HList`, I just thought there might be some `HList`-based magic I could spell.

For a little more context: I want to create a typesafe layer around a javaish API that requires casting around arrays that can have multi-dimensional arrays, the names are the names of the coordinate axes used to describe the data.

Comment: Thanks for asking more concise in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410653/is-there-infrastructure-in-shapeless-that-takes-a-type-constructor-to-the-power about shapeless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I observe correctly that the list contains elements of only type String, and you simply attach a "type tag" (`Float`) which you want to use to parameterize your nested Array? So you do not really have an `HList`, but you use the "`HList`" merely to count the nesting level?

The following code can be used to build nested Arrays by calling a `step` function. Adding the names should be trivial.

[scalafiddle.io](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/L6XgqYS/0)

```
trait I {
  type Out
  def step: I.Aux[Array[Out]] = I[Array[Out]]
  def create(x: Any): Out = x.asInstanceOf[Out]
}

object I {
  type Aux[X] = I {type Out = X}
  def apply[A]: Aux[A] = new I {type Out = A}
}

val x: Float = I[Float].create(1)

val ax: Array[Float] = I[Float].step.create(Array(0.1f))

val aax: Array[Array[Float]] = I[Float].step.step.create(Array(Array(0.1f)))

//The following fail to compile

//val aax2: Array[Array[Float]] = I[Float].step.create(Array(0.1f))
//val aax3: Array[Float] = I[Float].step.step.create(Array(0.1f))
```