# Is there infrastructure in shapeless that takes a type constructor to the power of a Nat?

Tags: scala, shapeless

To me this appears as a very basic functionality, but I can't find it in current shapeless (2.3.3).

So I am looking for a type `Induction[X,F[_],N <: Nat]` with

```
Induction[X,F,Nat._0].Out =:= X
Induction[X,F,Nat._1].Out =:= F[X]
Induction[X,F,Nat._2].Out =:= F[F[X]]
...
```

Maybe it's also possible to chain a function along the type construction, e.g., to construct a `Point` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. As you observe this most likely needs a `Point`-like type class to be useful. I suggest adding something like this to [Kittens](https://github.com/milessabin/kittens) which depends on both shapeless and Cats.